# I can't debug whats wrong with my ACF get_field() to display an image array's url value

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

So my code is pretty straightforward. I am just getting a field value from the global fields (Options). So this field is on Dashboard -> Options (I have ACFpro) and I am trying to echo out a logo which is an image array.

This is how my code looks like

```
                <ul class="text-white p-0">
                    <a class="brand " href="/">
                        <?php
                           $image = get_field('logo');
                           echo '<p id="debug">'.($image ['url']).'</p>';
                        ?>
                    </a>
                </ul>
```

al i am trying to do is pull the url value and insert it to a `<p>` tag just to make sure it pulls the right value. but instead I am getting this error.

[error when trying to echo $image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpKW5.png)

Any idea on what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is one of two things. You need to add the ID or options to the get_field() as a parameter or you need to adjust the return format. By default it tries to pull the ID of the page get_field() is on.

[image]

I would change it to

```
get_field( 'logo', 'options' );
```

Or change options to whatever you called your options page.

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/options-page/

Comment: duuh, I didn't know you had to do 'options ' for the fields that apply globally. That did the trick, thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome!